# Why does a transaction trigger 12 or 24 confirmation events?

Tags: web3js, transactions, confirmations, receipts

Web3.js docs state that a *confirmation* event will be fired:

- 12 times when calling `web3.eth.sendTransaction` (see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return))
- 24 times when calling `myContract.methods.myMethod.send` (see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id22))

Why is the difference in the number of times that the event is fired in each case?

More importantly, what exactly should I use these events for?

At present, I simply `await` for the function to complete, and then use the returned value, which is a resolved `Promise` containing the transaction receipt (unless we're dealing with a contract deployment, in which case it will contain the new contract's instance).

To my understanding, this receipt can also be obtained using:

```
myContract.methods.myMethod().send().on('receipt', function(receipt){...});
```

I assume that this additional way of obtaining the receipt is for when you also want to handle other things, such as those *confirmation* events, which from what I've observed, do not necessarily occur before the receipt is available.

Do I need to count up 12 (or 24) events in order to be sure that the information receipt reflects the block-chain?

Thank you!

Comment: When your transaction is mined, receipt will become available.... this is confirmation 0, as more blocks added into blockchain.... confidence increases that your transaction is on longest chain and can’t be undone...

Comment: @kherwa: Thank you. And does that confidence reach 100% after 12 (or 24) confirmation events? Or more generally, can the confidence level be measured as a function of the confirmation number? If yes, what exactly is the function? Also, does each confirmation event correspond to 1 block being added to the chain?

Comment: Yes each confirmation is a new block...  it is upto you to wait for certain number of confirmations depending upon nature and sensitivity of transaction...

Comment: @goodvibration so how you come up a solution, how are you making sure the transaction is completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a transaction is mined, the receipt is available for use, at this point confirmation number is 0, as more block are added to the blockchain, confirmation number increases. With higher confirmation number, we will have more confidence that transaction is on the longest path and can’t be undone.

Suppose you accept transactions with a certain number of confirmations, you can filter that confirmation number on confirmation event.

`.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber,receipt){})`

Regarding why the event is emitted up to 12 and 24 confirmations in different scenarios, I do not have much idea.

Comment: A confirmation event is fired 24 times in both cases (I tested it). The "12" is an error in the docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for jumping on a very old post how ever came across it looking for something else.

For those interested, the 24 confirmation events are being emitted due in fact  to 24 being the default internal Web3 setting for number of acceptable confirmations. This setting can be set to a lower or higher confirmation count.

**To read the current setting:**

```
web3.eth.transactionConfirmationBlocks
```

**To change the setting:**

```
web3.eth.transactionConfirmationBlocks = <new number>
```

See the Official Web3 documentation for further information here [Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#transactionblocktimeout)